# Gps not working sometimes in some of the applications for android

Tags: android, gps

I was working with Gps for fetching current lat and long in my application, it was working nicely with android 2.3.3 and even in some of my higher versions android devices but sometimes in some of the devices its just behaving opposite although gps is on its showing error message that GPS is not connected please turn on the gps this is the message i used when gps is not detecting. can anyone please help me on this ?
Below is my code for detecting and getting GPS

```
    private void bindgeocodelocation() {
    latlong = new ArrayList<String>();

    latlong = GeneralFunction.getcurrentlocation(Search.this);
    if (latlong == null) {
        LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Location loc = lm
                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 100, 1,
                locationListener);
        if (loc != null) {
            latlong = new ArrayList<String>();
            latlong.add("" + loc.getLatitude());
            latlong.add("" + loc.getLongitude());
        } else if (lm != null) {
            lm.removeUpdates(locationListener);
        }
    }

}

private final LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        try {
            latlong = new ArrayList<String>();
            latlong.add(location.getLatitude() + "");
            latlong.add(location.getLongitude() + "");
            // webviewdata();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage().toString());
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        Log.i("Info", "Provider disable");

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
};
```

Comment: i think you have to use best provider insted of LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER

Comment: @HetalPatel its not the issue of your code, it may be happen then some devices can not fetching location or not getting GPS connection. Go outside and then test it may work.

Comment: Actually in some of the devices its working but in some of the android versions its not detecting.. can it be possible some version related issues ?

Comment: no its not related to version level i thonk pratik is ri8 test outside first

Comment: @HetalPatel there may be some problem like, Google Play Services is not enabled from device, Play Services may be outdated, GPS signals are not fetching inside the home or office.

Comment: @hetalpatel Reboot your phone or just take google play services update or go outside once and then test.

Comment: @HetalPatel Samsung note series have problem in GPS, on which device are you testing?

Comment: @HetalPatel okay , try it and let us know as well.

Comment: ok sure will try it and will update

Comment: @HetalPatel its ok, happy coding....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then if you make that device outdoor for some time, it may work. In some low end devices, gps may not work properly at all. Else try upgrading GooglePlayServices too. Also I suggest you to use multiple providers instead of only one NETWORK_PROVIDER

Comment: actually she faces issue that she can not detect gps on or off in some devices so toatlly wrong direction answers you have given

Comment: I faced such issue in low end devices. Let her try this. It may work.

Comment: Also I suggest you to use multiple providers instead of only one  NETWORK_PROVIDER

Comment: no Digvesh, the app is working perfectly but in some of the android devices gps is not detecting.

Comment: I think there is some issue related to the android versions as its not stable.

Comment: Patel, update your google play services too... It might work if you keep your device outdoor. Worked for me.

Comment: Can you tell in which devices you are facing such Issue.?

Comment: In Galaxy s3, there are two devices of galaxy s3 from which one is working perfectly and in another seems error.

Comment: app->running servics->>> haveing running locationservices plz check it first

Comment: Galaxy s3 it should work fine. Check some other apps like google maps. try upgrading Google Play Services too

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the particular device's google play services are outdated 
I've faced the similar problem.
Your code seems fine
The only issue can be the google playe services are outdated.